# How to change symbol visibility of Ada libraries using gnat?

Tags: linux, visibility, ada, gnat

I'm having trouble porting my program to Linux because Linux has public symbol visibility by default. Currently, I have an executable and a .so shared object library, both written in Ada. They share some files, like these ones:

Common/my_program_generic.ads

```
generic package My_Program_Generic is
    Initialized : Boolean := False;

    procedure Initialize;
end My_Program_Generic;
```

Common/my_program_generic.adb

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

package body My_Program_Generic is
    procedure Initialize is
    begin
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Initialized: " & Initialized'Img);
        if not Initialized then
            Initialized := True;
            -- Do stuff
            Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Did stuff!");
        end if;
    end Initialize;
end My_Program_Generic;
```

Common/my_program.ads

```
with My_Program_Generic;
My_Program is new My_Program_Generic;
```

Both the executable and the library then call `My_Program.Initialize` from separate code.
Output (first & second lines is executable, third is library):

```
Initialized: FALSE
Did stuff!
Initialized: TRUE
```

The problem here is that the symbol visibility is public, so it seems the executable runs this function and initializes everything, but then the shared object library uses the executable's `My_Program.Initialized` (which is True) instead of its own (which is False), fails to initialize, then crashes later using an uninitialized variable.

I tried compiling with `-fvisiblity=hidden` for compiling everything (from both the makefile and the gnat project file (.gpr)), which seems to be properly passing it to the compiler (e.g. it shows on the command line `gcc -c -fPIC -g -m32 -fvisibility=hidden -gnatA my_file.adb`), but it doesn't seem to have made a difference, and I can't find any documentation for controlling visibility using gnat.

My OS is CentOS 5.6. I cannot upgrade to a newer version of Linux, but I could upgrade my GCC or gnat versions to anything that works on CentOS 5.6. My GCC/gnat versions follow:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)
...
$ gnatls -v
GNATLS 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)
...
```

Yes I know it says Red Hat, but I'm using CentOS. AFAIK they're perfectly compatible with each other anyway.

---

It's possible all information needed to solve my issue is fully explained above, but here's the rest of the code, makefiles, and gpr files you could use to recreate my binaries on your machine (for a more complete but less minimal illustration).

Library/my_library.ads

```
package My_Library is
    procedure Initialize_Library;
    pragma Export (DLL, Initialize_Library, "Initialize_Library");
end My_Library;
```

Library/my_library.adb

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with My_Program;

package body My_Library is
    procedure Initialize_Library is
    begin
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Initializing Library...");
        My_Program.Initialize;
    end Initialize_Library;
end My_Library;
```

Library/dummy.ads

```
package Dummy is
end Dummy;
```

Library/my_library.gpr

```
project My_Library is
    for source_dirs use (".","../Common");
    for Library_Src_Dir use "include";
    for object_dir use "obj";
    for library_dir use "lib";
    for library_name use "my_library";
    for library_kind use "dynamic";
    for library_interface use ("dummy");
    for library_auto_init use "true;
    -- Compile 32-bit
    for library_options use ("-m32");
    package compiler is
        for default_switches ("Ada")
            use ("-g", "-m32", "-fvisibility=hidden");
    end compiler;

    for Source_Files use (
        "my_program_generic.ads",
        "my_program_generic.adb",
        "my_program.ads",
        "dummy.ads",
        "my_library.ads",
        "my_library.adb");
end My_Library;
```

Library/Makefile

```
GNATMAKE=gnatmake
LDFLAGS=-shared
TARGETBASE=libMy_Library.so
GNATMAKEFLAGS=--RTS=/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2
TARGET=Debug/$(TARGETBASE)

# Phony target so make all will work
.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGET)

SRCS = \
    ../Common/my_program_generic.ads \
    ../Common/my_program_generic.adb \
    ../Common/my_program.adb \
    dummy.ads \
    my_library.ads \
    my_library.adb

CHOPPATH = chop
OBJPATH = obj
LIBPATH = lib

$(TARGET) : $(SRCS)
    $(GNATMAKE) -Pmy_library $(GNATMAKEFLAGS)
    mv $(LIBPATH)/$(TARGETBASE) $(TARGET)

# Phony target so make clean will work
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET) $(CHOPPATH)/*.ads $(CHOPPATH)/*.adb $(OBJPATH)/*.s $(OBJPATH)/*.o $(OBJPATH)/*.ads $(OBJPATH)/*.adb *.s $(LIBPATH)/*.so $(LIBPATH)/*.ali
```

Exe/my_exe.adb

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with My_Program;
with My_Library_Import;

procedure My_Exe is
begin
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("Begin main program.");
    My_Program.Initialize;
    My_Library_Import.Initialize_Library;
end My_Exe;
```

Exe/my_library_import.ads

```
package My_Library_Import is
    procedure Initialize_Library;
private
    type External_Initialize_Library_Type is access procedure;
    pragma Convention (DLL_Stdcall, External_Initialize_Library_Type);
    External_Initialize_Library : External_Initialize_Library_Type := null;
end My_Library_Import;
```

Exe/my_library_import.adb

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Unchecked_Conversion;
with System;
with Interfaces.C;
with Interfaces.C.Strings;
use type System.Address;

package body My_Library_Import is
    Library_Handle : System.Address := System.Null_Address;
    Library_Name : String := "../Library/Debug/libMy_Library.so";

    -- Interface to libdl to load dynamically linked libraries

    function dlopen(
        File_Name : in Interfaces.C.Strings.Chars_Ptr;
        Flag      : in Integer) return System.Address;
    pragma Import (C, dlopen);

    function dlsym(
        Handle : in System.Address;
        Symbol : in Interfaces.C.Char_Array) return System.Address;
    pragma Import (C, dlsym);

    function dlerror return Interfaces.C.Strings.Chars_Ptr;
    pragma Import (C, dlerror);

    function External_Initialize_Library_Type_Import is new Ada.Unchecked_Conversion(
        System.Address, External_Initialize_Library_Type);

    procedure Initialize_Library is
        Temp_Name : Interfaces.C.Strings.Chars_Ptr;
    begin
        -- Load Library
        Temp_Name := Interfaces.C.Strings.New_Char_Array(Interfaces.C.To_C(Library_Name));
        Library_Handle := dlopen(Temp_Name, 16#101#);  -- RTLD_NOW (0x0001), RTLD_GLOBAL (0x0100)
        Interfaces.C.Strings.Free(Temp_Name);

        -- Check for Load Library failure (did we execute from the right place?)
        if (Library_Handle = System.Null_Address) then
            Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("dlerror: " &
                Interfaces.C.Strings.Value(dlerror));
            return;
        end if;

        -- Get function access
        External_Initialize_Library := External_Initialize_Library_Type_Import(
            dlsym(Library_Handle, Interfaces.C.To_C("Initialize_Library")));

        -- Initialize library itself
        External_Initialize_Library.all;
    end Initialize_Library;
end My_Library_Import;
```

Exe/Makefile

```
CC=gcc
LD=g++
GNATCHOP=gnatchop
GNATMAKE=gnatmake
RC=windres

INCLUDE_PATH = -I.

LDFLAGS=-largs -ldl -lpthread -rdynamic -lstdc++
TARGET_FILE=my_exe
GNATMAKEFLAGS=--RTS=/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2
TARGET_PATH=Debug
TARGET=$(TARGET_PATH)/$(TARGET_FILE)

# Phony target so make all will work
.PHONY: all
all : $(TARGET)

SRCS = \
    ../Common/my_program_generic.ads \
    ../Common/my_program_generic.adb \
    ../Common/my_program.adb \
    my_exe.adb \
    my_library_import.ads \
    my_library_import.adb

CHOPPATH = chop
OBJPATH = obj

$(TARGET) : $(SRCS)
    $(GNATCHOP) $^ $(CHOPPATH) -w -r
    rm -rf *.s
    $(GNATMAKE) -m32 -j3 -g -gnatwA -fvisibility=hidden -D $(OBJPATH) -k $(CHOPPATH)/*.adb $(LDFLAGS) $(GNATMAKEFLAGS)
    rm -rf b~$(TARGET_FILE).*
    mv $(TARGET_FILE) $(TARGET)

# Phony target so make clean will work
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -rf $(TARGET) $(CHOPPATH)/*.ads $(CHOPPATH)/*.adb $(OBJPATH)/*.s $(OBJPATH)/*.o $(OBJPATH)/*.ads $(OBJPATH)/*.adb *.s
```

I'm not using a gpr file for the executable (Exe).

Execute the program from the "Exe" folder with `./Debug/my_exe`, and the full output with the additional files is as follows:

```
$ ./Debug/my_exe
Begin main program.
Initialized: FALSE
Did Stuff!
Initializing Library...
Initialized: TRUE
```

Comment: Why isn't `Initialized` in the private part of the package, or even in the package body? though I may be missing something about the question...

Comment: @BrianDrummond Moving the Boolean to the package body and recompiling both binaries doesn't appear to have changed anything. Is there anything about the question I can clarify?

Comment: What do you mean by `_Generic`? Is this in the Ada sense, or do you just mean "some random but typical example"?

Comment: @SimonWright It is actually in the Ada sense in the actual code (but clearly not for this MCVE), but I don't think it's relevant to my issue, i.e. the public visibility of the symbols to other libraries or the executable that loads the library.

Comment: So how do you turn this code into both a .so and an executable? You talk about a Makefile and a .gpr, where are they? They are part of what puts the CV in [MCVE]

Comment: I had to fight quite hard to get a Mac equivalent - but it did **not** show the behaviour you quote. Most of the problem was that gprbuild (for the main) couldn’t be persuaded not to see the code in the library; I ended up using gnatmake. Must be a Linux-only thing, as you say.

Comment: @BrianDrummond are you saying you were unable to verify, or you just haven't tried compiling something? Of course not every MCVE needs to include an entire Makefile, whether they use one or not, so I'm not sure what you're getting at. Particularly for this question, I was asking about existence of some sort of compile flag or gpr option, which shouldn't really necessitate a lot of code or an entire makefile. I'm currently trying a workaround. If it doesn't work, I'll update the question for you?

Comment: I will update the question with the build process when I get a chance, since everyone seems to think it's important, though I don't understand why it would be. In the meantime, I don't want to delete the Q, in case someone comes along that knows what I'm talking about already.

Comment: The symbols in the copy of actual.o that ends up in the .so must be global, or the rest of the .so couldn’t link. It’s only after the .so is finished that they can become local. This could be affected by the versions of compilers/Linux you’re using.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I've updated the question!

Comment: gcc4.1? Seriously? Wow ... No wonder others are having trouble reproducing the issue. This is archaeology, not programming. I'd try again with something more like gnat/gcc4.9 at least. You might experiment with Adacore's Libre edition, if your license requirements allow gpl, or see what's available for Centos at www.getadanow.com

Comment: @BrianDrummond I revisited this problem, and the issue is still present in GCC/gnat 8.2 (latest version). I'm not sure why you're unable to reproduce it. We've since determined that, even in newer versions, anything in a package specification gets forced to public/global, even when declared `private`. See my accepted answer for more details.

Comment: @KeithM Out of curiosity, did you ever try getting rid of my_program.ads and just instantiating it individually in both the library and the main application (once in my_exe.adb and once in my_library.adb)?  That might force two different symbols for you.  I'm not sure why linux would require that over macOS though.

Comment: @Jere If you name the package the same, the symbols have the same name, and there's a conflict. For my application, I can't change that fact. I have multiple libraries which all need to call this function, and it would be crazy to have unique names for all of them because I have over 30 libraries, and it's not as simple as presented here. I'd have to rename almost everything. BTW, you can check symbol visibility with `readelf` and the like, as well. Even in the .o object files, the symbols are already public/global/exported.

Comment: @Jere To be clear, we've done additional testing, and the problem is present in non-generic packages, as well.

Comment: @KeithM I wasn't suggesting you manually change the names.  The suggestion was to attempt to move the symbol from global to local by having them instantiated closer to where they are used.  This would potentially force GNAT to name them differently internally, but you could continue to call them My_Program everywhere you used it.  Since the package is declared at library level, that might be what is causing you a problem (I don't know why it would be a problem in linux vs others).  Just something to try.

Comment: @Jere Yes, we tried that. GNAT uses the full package chain to name them, so you can make them have different exported names by either (a) having a separate package name for each library and one for the executable, or (b) moving them inside the package where they're used. I think this is not too dissimilar from my workaround using `renames` below. The two problems with your idea that (1) the package is referenced in more than one other package, and it needs to be the same instance, so we can't do (b), and (2) <continued>

Comment: <continued from previous comment> (2) even if we went through the trouble of doing (a), `-- Do stuff` calls functions in other packages that resolve to the same symbols anyway.

Comment: This is just my MCVE btw to reproduce the compiler issue. In the real world, we're trying to load two copies of the same library, but at runtime, ALL symbols in ALL package specifications are resolving to the same address because that's what happens when you export gobs of symbols and load with `RTLD_GLOBAL` (see my answer about the `dlopen` workaround for more detail on that). Unless you can change the visibility or use `RTLD_LOCAL`, it's impossible to get around. That's why I said I'm looking for functionality like `-fvisiblity=hidden` with C/C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found another workaround, which is to change the `dlopen` call flags from `RTLD_GLOBAL` to `RTLD_LOCAL`:

```
Library_Handle := dlopen(Temp_Name, 16#101#);  -- RTLD_NOW (0x0001), RTLD_GLOBAL (0x0100)
```

to

```
Library_Handle := dlopen(Temp_Name, 16#1#);  -- RTLD_NOW (0x0001), RTLD_LOCAL (0x0000)
```

However, in this manner, you need the full file path and name every time the library is loaded (or put the path in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable), and NONE of the exported symbols will be immediately visible, so you'll need to call `dlsym` to fetch any symbols you need to use, like in the line from the question:

```
-- Get function access
External_Initialize_Library := External_Initialize_Library_Type_Import(
    dlsym(Library_Handle, Interfaces.C.To_C("Initialize_Library")));
```

This way, you can at least manage what symbols are "visible" -- by having none of them actually visible, and fetching the ones you need explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know what you’re doing differently from me, because you haven’t told us what your build process is or what versions of OS/compiler you’re using. Also, I can’t reproduce your exact result, because you haven’t provided a complete demonstrator.

I believe the answer lies in an undocumented (but desirable) feature of recent releases of *gprbuild* (I used the one provided with GNAT GPL 2016, on both macOS Sierra and Debian jessie).

I wrote a library containing an instantiator,

```ada
with My_Program_Generic;
package Actual is new My_Program_Generic;
```

a different copy which of course is also in the main program’s closure, and another package to be included only in the library,

```ada
package In_Library with Elaborate_Body is
end In_Library;

with Actual;
with Ada.Text_IO;
package body In_Library is
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("In_Library's elaboration");
   Actual.Initialize;
end In_Library;
```

The point of this is to avoid revealing the presence of `Actual` in the library, because otherwise there would certainly be two versions in the main program’s closure.

I built the library with this [standalone GPR](http://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug/gnat_project_manager.html#stand-alone-library-projects),

```ada
library project Build is
   for Library_Name use "keith";
   for Library_Kind use "dynamic";
   for Library_Dir use "lib";
   for Library_Src_Dir use "include";
   for Library_Interface use ("In_Library");
   for Object_Dir use ".build";
   for Source_Files use ("my_program_generic.ads",
                         "my_program_generic.adb",
                         "actual.ads",
                         "in_library.ads",
                         "in_library.adb");
end Build;
```

and (a recent enough) *gprbuild* recognises that `Actual` isn’t in the `Library_Interface` **and converts its symbols, which were global,  to local**!!!

By "recent enough" I mean no earlier than the one released with GNAT GPL 2016.

You can get a hint of the method used to achieve this by examining `$prefix/share/gprconfig/linker.xml` for a section containing `Object_Lister`. For example,

```xml
<configuration>
  <targets>
    <target name="^i686.*-linux.*$" />
  </targets>
  <hosts>
    <host name="^i686.*-linux.*$" />
  </hosts>
  <config>
 for Object_Lister use ("nm", "-g");
 for Object_Lister_Matcher use " [TDRB] (.*)";

 package Linker is
    for Export_File_Format use "GNU";
    for Export_File_Switch use "-Wl,--version-script=";
 end Linker;
  </config>
</configuration>
```

would be used for some Linux; it looks as if you use `nm -g` on the compiled interface units and copy the symbols of some global types into a temporary file in GNU format, which is passed to the linker via the `--version-script=` switch.

The macOS variant passes the symbols in flat format, using the `-exported_symbols_list` switch.

---

Normally one would import the library using a GPR with the [`Externally_Built` attribute](http://docs.adacore.com/gprbuild-docs/html/gprbuild_ug/gnat_project_manager.html?highlight=externally_built#importing-projects),

```ada
library project Keith is
   for Library_Name use "keith";
   for Library_Kind use "dynamic";
   for Library_Dir use "lib";
   for Library_Src_Dir use "include";
   for Externally_Built use "true";
end Keith;
```

but *gprbuild* remained aware that the same source units were in the library project and the using project and refused to build, leaving me to link with

```
$ gnatmake -f \
  -aIlibrary/include -aOlibrary/lib \
  main.adb \
  -bargs -shared \
  -largs -Llibrary/lib -lkeith
```

Comment: My version of `Actual` is not in the `Library_Interface`, yet its symbol is still global. Is this still on Mac, like you said in the question comments? I will update the question with the build process when I get a chance, since everyone seems to think it's important, though I don't understand why it would be.

Comment: I had said that I’ve tried the same source/build on macOS and on Debian jessie, with the same results, but lost it in an edit. Back again now. The symbols in actual.o are global, but the symbols in libkeith.so (.dylib on Mac) are local!!!

Comment: `By "recent enough" I mean no earlier than the one released with GNAT GPL 2016.` Do you mean to say that you (a) tried this with earlier versions and the symbols remained public, or that you (b) haven't yet tried earlier versions but anything more recent than 2016 should work?

Comment: I've updated the question with my build process. I tried calling initialization in the elaboration, but it doesn't change anything. Perhaps my version is too old? Would it be possible for you to try an older version?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `renames` to change which symbols are public. Take this file

> Common/my_program.ads
>
> ```
> with My_Program_Generic;
> My_Program is new My_Program_Generic;
> ```

and JUST for the library, create a new copy, edited like so:

Library/my_program_library_private.ads

```
 with My_Program_Generic;
 My_Program_Library_Private is new My_Program_Generic;
```

But now your code referencing `My_Program` won't compile, so create a new file:

Library/my_program.ads

```
with My_Program_Library_Private;
package My_Program renames My_Program_Library_Private;
```

This allows you to hide the symbol from the executable while also avoiding changing the guts of the code. Now `My_Program_Library_Private.Initialize` is a public symbol, but `My_Program.Initialize` is not.

Before:

```
$ nm -g Debug/libMy_Library.so
000010fc T Initialize_Library
...
00001438 T my_program__initialize
```

After:

```
$ nm -g Debug/libMy_Library.so
0000112c T Initialize_Library
...
000011b0 T my_program_library_private__initialize
```

`my_program__*` is not even listed in the symbols.

And the output is now:

```
$ ./Debug/my_exe
Begin main program.
Initialized: FALSE
Did Stuff!
Initializing Library...
Initialized: FALSE
Did Stuff!
```

Comment: This solution works for me, but I would prefer a different solution. Renaming packages and creating new files to `rename` them would be tedious and time-consuming for my non-MCVE actually-relatively-large program.

Answer (score 0):

My employer was finally able to upgrade to new(er) Linux computers, upgrading our GCC from GCC version `4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-50)` to `4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)`.

As of at least this new version (4.4.7), the issue is not as severe in the newer versions of gnat/gcc, like @BrianDrummond predicted in the question comments. Only symbols that are in package specifications are made public/global, even when declared `private`. Symbols that appear only in a package body are made private/local.

However, there is still no way to explicitly make symbols private/local.

This new issue is still present in GCC 8.2, the current latest version.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing from "my_program_generic.ads" can end up in an object file, as it is a generic package, so I don't think you have anything to worry about.

Comment: Obviously I do have something to worry about, or I wouldn't have the output shown in the question. If it's not clear, the executable and the library both each create an instance of the generic package.

Comment: The demonstration code in your question does not contain any generic instatiations.  Please show us what is **actually** going wrong.

Comment: Because it's truly as simple as `My_Program is new My_Program_Generic;`. I don't think adding such trivial pieces of code are helpful, but I've added it anyway, since you ask for it. I will also update the question with the build process when I get a chance, since everyone seems to think it's important, though I don't understand why it would be.